# Migration from GitHub API v3 to v4

Tags: github-api

I have an integration with GitHub that uses the REST API v3. However I see there is the GraphQL API v4, which is the newer one.

For me it is just easier to keep using the REST API v3, however I can't find anywhere in GitHub docs if this API is going to be deprecated in the near feature in favor of the GraphQL API v4.

Should I migrate to v4 or is it safe to stay with v3? Is there any scheduled end of life for v3?

Comment: I was not able to find any deprecation notices for v3 REST API. The https://developer.github.com/early-access/platform-roadmap has no information.